# Background service on Ionic 2 geofence won't trigger

Tags: java, ionic2, geofencing, android-geofence

I'm working on an Ionic app that requires geofence to run in the background. I'm using the [cordova-plugin-geofence](https://github.com/cowbell/cordova-plugin-geofence) plugin. I understand that JavaScript does not run in the background and that the plugin developer provided native code to listen to geofence transitions.

I followed the instructions but it doesn't seem to work. Transition does not trigger when the app is closed.

Here is my package name: `io.ionic.pla`.

I placed this code below in my Android Manifest

```
        <receiver android:name="io.ionic.pla.TransitionReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.cowbell.cordova.geofence.TRANSITION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Here is my TransitionReceiver.java

```
            package io.ionic.pla;

            import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
            import android.content.Context;
            import android.content.Intent;
            import android.util.Log;

            import com.cowbell.cordova.geofence.Gson;
            import com.cowbell.cordova.geofence.GeoNotification;

            public class TransitionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    String error = intent.getStringExtra("error");

                    if (error != null) {
                        //handle error
                        Log.println(Log.ERROR, "YourAppTAG", error);
                    } else {
                        String geofencesJson = intent.getStringExtra("transitionData");
                        Log.println(Log.INFO, "xxxYourAppTAG", geofencesJson);
                        GeoNotification[] geoNotifications = Gson.get().fromJson(geofencesJson, GeoNotification[].class);
                        //handle geoNotifications objects
                    }
                }
            }
```

Please help guys, I really need this to work.

Comment: were you able to get this working?

Comment: Unfortunately No!!